# Create Issue using JIRA rest API return the error Method not allowed

Tags: api, post, jira

I'm trying to create issue using JIRA rest API by the following code

```
 string data = @"{ ""fields"": {
                            ""project"":
               {
                   ""key"": ""TEST""
               },
                            ""summary"": ""Test Ticket"",
                            ""description"": ""Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API"",
                            ""issuetype"": {
                                ""name"": ""Bug""
                            },
                            ""assignee"": { ""xx"": ""xxx"" }
                        }
        }";
        string postUrl = "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/";
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(postUrl);
        byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xx:xx");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        //System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<Issue>(data, jsonFormatter);
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;
```

I got unexpected error : "Method not allowed"

Comment: Just a comment regarding url: there is 'issue' in url and also in PostAsync call, did you check what url the request goes to?

Comment: I recommend using Fiddler and checking the request url and request body and enrich your question with this data

Comment: Its working fine on RestClient

Comment: the problem in json structure when put it in file and read it , its working fine thank you Robert.

Comment: That was my second guess :) Glad it works..

Answer (score 0):

I second @Robert, the first parameter of `PostAsync` is called `requestUri`, so your `postUrl` comes here. Then you can skip the `BaseAddress` setup.

As you have a `BaseAddress` and a relative URI as `requestUri`, HttpClient most likely combines them into `http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/issue` and uses this URL in the actual POST request, and THAT target does not allow POST.

Comment: Did you also change the PostAsync call?

Comment: yes i put the full url (localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue) in PostAsync